# Replace repo's branch content without clone

Tags: git

I maintain an internal repo that is meant to mirror specific versions in a public repo. Something like this:

```
$ git log --pretty=oneline

13er55 (HEAD -> main, tag: 0.2.0, origin/main) Import version 0.2.0 
25qq80 (tag: 0.1.2) Import version 0.1.2 
95fe82 (tag: 0.1.1) Import version 0.1.1 
87bf62 (tag: 0.1.0) Import version 0.1.0
```

Whenever I need to import a new version, I clone the original repo and copy the whole content at a certain tag to somewhere temporarily:

```
git clone https://github.com/whatever/repo -b 0.2.1
mkdir ../_tmp; mv * .* ../_tmp;
```

then, I clone my repo and replace the whole content (except .git directory) with that content and commit / tag:

```
git clone -b main --single-branch https://github.com/whatever/my_mirror_repo --depth=1 .
rm -rf ../_tmp/.git; mv .git ../_tmp; rm -rf * .*
mv ../_tmp/* ../_tmp/.* .

git add . && git commit -am 'Import version \(version) '
git tag \(version)
git push; git push --tags
```

to do that in the most efficient way, I clone my mirror repo with `--single-branch` & `--depth=1`, but I feel like I can do better. The point is, I'm going to replace the whole content anyway so I don't really care about any file in my mirror repo.

I'm looking for a way to replace the whole content in my mirror repo, but without the overhead of downloading anything. Like if I can reset the HEAD to the my mirror repo's HEAD and base on that without downloading any existing file. Does that make sense? Is this the best way?

**Edit:**

The goal of the script I'm writing is to import versions from third party repos, to comply with policies. This way the versions can be served from internal repos we own.

So, for every third party repo, we need to import specific versions at certain tags. Along the way, we might need to run the script again to import different versions, and so on.

What I'm trying to achieve is that for every version we need to import, I want to add the content that reflects the state of the original repo at that tag, squash it into a single commit and tag it with the corresponding tag.

Comment: You don't need to reclone the repository. Just keep a separate branch that tracks the remote repository, and merge that into your local branch instead.

Comment: @chepner How do you merge into the local branch? I tried clearing everything via `git rm -rf .; git clean -fxd` and then use `git merge --squash --allow-unrelated-histories` but in some cases I get `Already up to date.` message even though the branch is empty.

Comment: I don't know why you are trying to (re)move anything. Clone the repository, and fetch new versions as they become available.

Comment: Because versions are not guaranteed to be merged in an incremental order. I probably wasn't clear, but the goal is to make a script where the user can point to any version and the script will import it and commit it. To avoid conflicts I want to overwrite the whole content of the branch each time with the state at the target version.

Comment: It's not really clear what's going on here, but it sounds like somebody using Git in a way it was not intended to be used. You can have *all* the versions in your repository at all times, and extract whichever one you want as needed.

Comment: I've edited the question with the use case / final goal. Hope that clarifies it more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So, for every third party repo, we need to import specific versions at certain tags. Along the way, we might need to run the script again to import different versions, and so on.

The fact that the third-party repo is (or isn't) a Git repository is *not very important*, but if the third-party repo *is* a Git repository, that makes the commands a bit easier to use.  You will, however, have to make some decisions and write some code (shell scripts will be fine here).  It's unwise to take some random recipe off the Internet and use it without understanding what's going on, though.

#### Background

Remember that each commit *in* a Git repository is a full snapshot of every file (plus metadata).  As such, you simply need to make, in your own repository, a new snapshot from one of these snapshots you *extract from* the third-party repo.

Consider, for example, what happens if the third-party-repo snapshots are delivered to you as tarballs (or some similar archive format): `v2.3.tar`, `v2.4.tar`, and so on.  To add these two tarballs to your existing Git repository, you will want to make one commit *from* each tarball.

Git makes new commits from whatever is in Git's *index*, not what is in some working tree.  However, the easy, user-oriented way to fill up some index *from* some set of files stored in some working tree is to:

1. Empty the index completely: `git rm -r --cached .` for instance, or (shorter) `git read-tree --empty` (but this cannot be combined with `-u`, so maybe `git rm` is better).
2. Add all files from some working tree, e.g., `git add .` (assuming you are at the top level of the working tree, there are no `.gitignore` traps, and so on; we'll look at another way to do this in a moment).

So assuming no `.gitignore` traps, we could:

```
git rm -rf .             # empty index and remove current checked out files
git clean -dfx           # discard all untracked files too, to get clean work-tree
tar xf ../v2.3.tar       # extract bundle
git add .                # fill in index from extracted files
```

The index is now prepared.  The main problem is that running `git commit` makes the new commit on the *current branch*, so we must use something else instead:

```
tree=$(git write-tree)   # turn index into tree object
commit=$(git commit-tree -p <parent> -m "vendor supplied v2.3" $tree)
git update-ref refs/vendor/v2.3 $commit
```

for instance.  The `-p parent` argument is optional but if given, will chain the new commit just made to some previous commit, e.g., to vendor 2.2 version.  The `refs/vendor/` prefix is a namespace I just made up to hold the vendor's tags.  You could use anything you like here, including ordinary tags in the `refs/tags/` namespace.  If using `refs/vendor` and you desire to have the new commit link back to the vendor's 2.2 version, the parent could be named as `refs/vendor/v2.2`, assuming of course you already made that commit (commits must be made in "forward order" here, just as they are when using Git in an ordinary fashion).

#### The problems with the above

There are some obvious problems, with simple fixes:

1. We have to wreck the working tree.  This one is easy to work around, using `git worktree`, and if we cannot use the super-short-cut trick of depending on the third-party-repo being a *Git* repository to which we have direct access, that's probably the way to go.  (This also means we can drop the `git clean` step, and maybe a few others.)
2. This depends on the `git add .` to actually add *all* the files.  Some commits (and resulting tarballs) might contain file path names as committed files that are nonetheless listed in `.gitignore`.  To fix this, we can simply use `git add -f .`, since we carefully empty out the working tree of all files.
3. There's no obvious way to identify which commit should be treated as the parent.  An easy(ish) fix for that is to have a `vendor` *branch*, which lets us use `git commit` instead of `git write-tree` and `git commit-tree`; we can then replace the last command with `git update-ref refs/vendor/v2.3 HEAD`.

Combining these gives us:

```
git worktree add ../vendor -b vendor
cd ../vendor
# no need for "git clean" here
```

as a setup step to create the `vendor` branch in a separate `vendor` directory.  Its history will end at the *current commit*, so if that's not desired—if this history should be completely independent—we might want to do a `git checkout --orphan vendor` or `git switch --orphan vendor` after the `cd ../vendor` step.

Now that we have the vendor branch, we un-tar any given tarball with:

```
git rm -rf .
tar xf <path to tar-file>
git add -f .
git commit -m "vendor version $version"
git update-ref refs/vendor/$version HEAD
```

That's the whole script, aside from the obvious need to check for failures and get `$version` from somewhere, plus any tweaking you might like.

#### If the third-party repo is a Git repo and you can read it

If we assume that the third-party repo is a Git repo that you can read, you can replace the "extract vendor version" three-step commands:

```
git rm -rf .
tar xf <path to tar-file>
git add -f .
```

with a simple:

```
git read-tree -u $tree
```

The only problem, such as it is, is that you must get the specific commit *into* your repository so that you *have* the tree.  If the vendor repo is available on a remote named `vendor`, you would just run:

```
git fetch vendor
```

or:

```
git fetch vendor <refspec>
```

(see [the `git fetch` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-fetch) for a description of refspecs) so as to get that.  The `$tree` is then, e.g., their `refs/tags/v2.3^{tree}`.  You'd probably want a refspec along the lines of:

```
git fetch vendor +refs/tags/v2.3:refs/temp
```

and then `refs/temp^{tree}` contains the tree hash to feed to `git read-tree -u`.  Once you've obtained the tree (or made the commit and the `refs/vendor/` tag that goes with it), you can delete the temporary `refs/temp` ref with `git update-ref -d refs/temp`.

This obviates the need to fuss with tarballs or other archives.  Note, however, that `git fetch vendor` will bring over some or even all of their commits, which will take a bunch of space.  Use of a refspec, and (optionally) `--depth 1`, will reduce the need for space, but it has a cost: a full fetch gets your Git repository enough information to reduce the network bandwidth on future fetches (and pushes to your own clones).  A shallow fetch doesn't and you might prefer to spend disk space, rather than network bandwidth and time.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate the time you took to write this detailed answer.